# Noise modifier for Wind Strength in F-Curve does not show the red lines

Tags: modifiers, fcurves

Was following a tutorial and I am following everything step by step.

I want to make papers float and need to adjust wind with noise modifier but when I am on F-curve and add Noise modifier the red lines are not showing...

Here is the tutorial (with specific time) I am following everything step by step https://youtu.be/9Nx38iwliZI?t=242

Here is the blender file:
[image]

What am i doing wrong, the wind force is selected, F-curve comes up and Noise modifier is added but no red lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press the home button in the graph editor (mouse hovering over graph editor), then it will appear.

[image]

Comment: Chris I love you man hahahaha

Comment: you are welcome ;)